# Can cloud-config be used to provision a Vagrant box?

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-provision, cloud-init

I'd like set up a development Vagrant VM using the same [could-config](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/format.html#cloud-config-data) file I'd use to provision a production VM. Vagrant doesn't have a built-in cloud-init/cloud-config provisioner, though. Is there still some way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Cloud-Init is not nativelly supported on Vagrant box images, instead the included *vagrant provision* do the job.

However there is a way to do it with VirtualBox

1. Install from scratch a VM using the distro ISO
2. Install cloud-init on the VM.
3. Stop and convert the VM to template.

Then the deployment of a new VM

1. Save the user-data and meta-data as an iso file
2. Clone the template and start it with the iso attached